# On Jupiter Notebook, when I create subplots one by one, Why don't I get only the final figure displayed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

When I use fig.update (or any updating function of my figure) or create subplots one by one (without displaying them, using add_trace), the current state of the figure is displayed. It is annoying because I want only the final figure to be displayed.

For example, when I write the following code, I get 6 figures displayed in this order:

- 1 figure for each add_trace:
  - first figure : only the first trace
  - 2nd figure : the first and the second traces
  - 3rd figure : the first, second and third traces
  - etc
- 1 figure with the four traces and the new layout (caused by the update_layout function)
- 1 figure similar to the precedent, caused by the fig.show()

Here is the code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
              row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[4000, 5000, 6000], y=[7000, 8000, 9000]),
              row=2, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=500, width=700,
                  title_text="Multiple Subplots with Titles")

fig.show()
```

Comment: I tried to run your code in my environment. It shows the correct 4 graphs. I checked both my environment 5.7.0 Colab environment 5.6.0. Which version are you currently using?

Comment: I have Jupyter Notebook version 6.4.5 on Anaconda

Comment: I guess I didn't word it right, it's the PLOTLY version.